# MongoDB C# Save random json data both array and object

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi, mongodb-.net-driver, asp.net-core-3.1

I am having difficulties with saving random json data to the mongodb. Persisting data to the db with .Net Core 3.1 Web API. **the data could be single object, array or array in object etc..**

Example json:

```
  {
        "defId" : NUUID("de7564ca-6e2c-43fb-bbf4-0506e0b44f2d"),
        "value" : "1521d88f-3a05-4afc-a2d6-d2dac794320f"
    }, 
    {
        "defId" : NUUID("a157b18d-27d4-48bd-a1f3-8a28f125257b"),
        "value" : "[\"1242d305-b377-48aa-87a7-54e48dee3f25\",\"b5217f2e-f26d-40fd-9d2b-3c424d1bb377\"]"
    }
```

Here i am serializing this json as follows, it is a definitely bad code.

```
item.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(item.Value.ToString()));
```

with that i am able to return data as string and then at the front end side, using JSON.parse helps me to use data.

**QUESTION**

How i could save arbitrary data like regular json document object? I also tried to save it as BsonDocument, when i do that following picture happens.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what about putting your arbitary document into a single field?

Comment: Use BsonDocument?